# DataLoader issue with Unicode special charactes handling

Tags: data-loader

I have a Data Loader CLI script importing data (Lead records) automatically from csv based on some schedule. Last week I stumbled upon following issue:

DataLoader (both CLI and GUI version) doesn't support special Unicode characters(symbols)!

Issue occurred when one of the Leads had LastName equal to . Since LastName is required on Lead the batch failed.

It's quite easy to reproduce:

1. Create Lead with FirstName = John, LastName =  in SF
2. Download it with DataLoader (remember about write as UTF-8 setting)
3. Try inserting the same CSV file with DataLoader
4. You should then get:
   [image: Data loader err]

For this:

```
"ID","LASTNAME","FIRSTNAME"
"00Q1l000001ONm7EAG","A",""
```

I got success in DataLoader:

[image: Data Loader result print scr]

but invalid record in SF:
[image: SF print scr]

Now interesting thing:

1. Other unicode like Japanese characters are working fine
2. I can of course create such Lead manually without DataLoader
3. I have Read + Write all CSVs with UTF-8 set and looks like (when exporting or trying to import that in CSVs the encoding is fine).

Any ideas? Did anyone else have such an issue?

Comment: This is silly, but do you have the last version? Also, have you tried the Data Import Wizard?

Comment: Thanks @SebastianKessel, no silly questions here :) But yes, I'm using latest version (44). I didn't try Data Import Wizard. It's not a one-time import, but a scheduled script so I will need to stick to Data Loader CLI

Comment: @neff Still researching this issue, but I would suggest looking at Salesforce DX. It has a data import feature, uses the command-line, and supports UTF-8 correctly without being so finicky.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox Good point with Salesforce DX, haven't thought about it. You mean `data:bulk:upsert`, right? I have everything set up in Data Loader CLI but maybe I need to switch in future.

Comment: @neff Yeah, the `force:data:bulk:upsert` function is the one I was thinking of. It does practically everything the data loader can do without all the extra configuration options. Granted, there's arguably still a use for either, but I'd take sfdx over ADL any day of the week, if possible.